# Distribute Points on Faces on small objects

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

[image]

[image]
Obviously i'm working on a donut. The points are huge, larger than the donut itself. Is there any way to adjust the point size? My donut is about 10cm in diameter.

Yes i know my instance on points node is disconnected, this is intentional to show the Point sizes.

Comment: You can adjust the size of the points with the *Set Point Radius* node. But when you instance objects on the points the size should not matter.

Comment: Thank you! I know they dont change the instances, but it helps to visualize the point distribution before instancing. If you set that as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the size of the points with the ***Set Point Radius*** node. But when you instance objects on the points the size should not matter.

*(sorry, no screenshot. The file upload does not work)*